# Appcelerator alloy custom listview item layout not working?

Tags: listview, layout, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, listviewitem

I created a listview following the example at
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_ListView_Guide

The view xml is as below,

```
<ListView id="elementsList" defaultItemTemplate="elementTemplate">
    <Templates>
        <ItemTemplate name="elementTemplate">
            <Label bindId="symbol" id="symbol" />
            <View id="atomProperties">
                <Label bindId="name" id="name" />
                <View id="secondLine">
                    <Label class="line2 fieldLabel" text="Number: " />
                    <Label class="line2" bindId="number" id="number" />
                    <Label class="line2 fieldLabel" text="Atomic Mass: " />
                    <Label class="line2" bindId="mass" id="mass" />
                </View>
            </View>
            <ImageView bindId="image" id="image" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <ListSection>
        <ListItem symbol:text="H" symbol:color="#090" name:text="Hydrogen" number:text="1" mass:text="1.00794"/>
        <ListItem symbol:text="He" symbol:color="#090" name:text="Helium" number:text="2" mass:text="4.002602"/>
        <ListItem symbol:text="Li" name:text="Lithium" number:text="3" mass:text="6.941"/>
    </ListSection>
</ListView>
```

And the tss is as below,

```
"#symbol": {
    left: 15,
    color: "black",
    font: { fontSize: 34, fontWeight: 'bold' }
},
"#symbol[platform=android]": {
    left: 0
}
"#atomProperties": {
    top: 0, left: 80, right: 0, bottom: 0,
    layout: "vertical"
},
"#atomProperties[platform=android]": {
    left: 65
},
"#name": {
    left: 0, top: 4,
    color: "black",
    textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
    font: { fontSize: 16 }
},
"#secondLine": {
    left: 0, right: 0,
    layout: "horizontal"
},
".fieldLabel": {
    color:"#999"
},
".line2": {
    font: { fontSize: 10 }
},
"#number": {
    width: 30,
    color: 'red'
},
"#mass": {
    color: "blue"
}
```

I need to add a right justified time label beside name and I need label mass to be right justified as well. So I add a time label below name

```
<Label bindId="name" id="name" />
<Label bindId="time" id="time" />
```

and then I add a tss

```
"#time": {
    right: 0, top: 4,
    color: "black",
    textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT,
    font: { fontSize: 12 }
}
```

time label is right justified correctly but then it will appear below name label. How do i make it same line as name?

And I want to label mass to be right justified so I change it to

```
"#mass": {
    color: "blue",
    right: 0,
    textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT
}
```

But it won't work, label mass still will not justified. How do I make it right justified?

Basically, I want my listview item layout to look like this

```
        name             time
SYMBOL
        number           mass
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the ItemTemplate to have horizontal layout.  Symbol label first with left spacing (you may also need to play with height and verticalAlign to get proper alignment).  Second is a view with vertical layout including name and number; a left setting here is the margin spacing from symbol.  Third is a view with vertical layout including time and mass; a left setting here is the margin spacing from the name/number view.  You may need to add top spacing for number and mass to get your desired effect.  Pseudo-ish-code below:

```
<ItemTemplate layout="horizontal">
    <Label text="Symbol" left="0"></Label>
    <View left="10" layout="vertical">
        <Label text="name">
        <Label text="number">
    </View>
    <View left="10" layout="vertical">
        <Label text="time">
        <Label text="mass">
    </View>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi, i adjusted your code as per advice 

`<ItemTemplate name="mytemplate" layout="horizontal">
        <Label text="Symbol" left="0"></Label>
        <View left="10" layout="vertical">
            <Label text="name"/>
            <Label top="5" text="number"/>
        </View>
        <View left="50" layout="vertical">
            <Label text="time"/>
            <Label top="5" text="mass"/>
        </View>
    </ItemTemplate>`

But it is still not working and the concept doesn't seems right. See captured image from android simulator below,
!(http://i68.tinypic.com/jzzb79.png)

Comment: Your image shows them still stacked vertically.  Try inserting a View container inside your ItemTemplate.  For example, <ItemTemplate> <View layout="horizontal"> <Label text="Symbol" left="0"></Label>...

Comment: Tried added a view container <View layout="horizontal"> still the same. I wonder if the listview itself is internally layout as vertical causing this behaviour?